# Python: Failed to import extension - Errno 2

Tags: python, mercurial, path, pythonpath

I am having weird behaviors in my Python environment on Mac OS X Lion.
Apps like Sublime Text (based on Python) don't work (I initially thought it was an app bug),
and now, after I installed hg-git, I get the following error every time I lauch HG in term:

`*** failed to import extension hggit from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-package/hggit/: [Errno 2] No such file
or directory`

So it probably is a Python environment set up error. Libraries and packages are there in place.
Any idea how to fix it?

Notes:

- I installed hg-git following hg-git web site directions.
- I also added the exact path to the extension in my .hgrc file as: `hggit = /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-package/hggit/`
- Python was installed using official package on Python web site.
- Echoing `$PYTHONPATH` in term print anything

Comment: What is the output of: import sys; print sys.path ?

Comment: Here it is my [sys.path](http://snipzone.com/a50227215)

Answer (score 0):

"site-package"? Did you mean "site-packages"?

Comment: Yep, thanks a lot, the path was wrong, but I still got the error:

`*** failed to import extension hggit from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/hggit/: No module named dulwich.errors`

Comment: Looks like that solved your initial problem. You are missing the dulwich package now, which can be found at https://github.com/jelmer/dulwich/archives/master (I think).

Comment: Ok, thanks to the nice guys at the HG IRC channel, I found out why Mercurial was not able to import extensions.
I installed my copy of Python (2.7.3) on my Mac but Mercurial (the official Mac .dmg package) was compiled to run on System Python (`/usr/bin/python`). And, since I installed hg-git with `easy_install hg-git` (which runs with my 2.7.3 python) it was not found by the **"bound to the system python"** HG.
How to fix it? Just install hg-git (and any other HG extension) with the system easy_install
E.g. `/usr/bin/easy_install hg-git`

Comment: Note:

**Do not** change `#/usr/bin/python` to `#/usr/bin/env python` in your `/usr/local/bin/hg` file, it would create issues (HG not working, earthquakes, nuclear fissions, etc.) when you will use environments related services or applications like VirtualEnv.